# Cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, bool>'

Tags: c#, dictionary, recursion, c#-6.0

I can't seem to add values into the dictionary. I am trying to extend the dictionary recursively but keep on getting the error/warning: "Cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, bool>'". I am a beginner so I am not sure how to resolve this error.

**I am getting the error on the last line in the return statement specifically the model.Add(p,true) part.**

[image: Error Image]

```
namespace InferenceEngine
{
    internal class TruthTable
    {
        TruthTable() { }

        private List<string> ExtractSymbol(Sentence KB)
        {
            List<string> result = new List<string>();

            if(KB.symbol != null)
            {
                result.Add(KB.symbol);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach(Sentence s in KB.child)
                {
                    result.Concat(ExtractSymbol(s));    
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        private bool PL_True(Sentence KB, Dictionary<string,bool> model)
        {
            if(KB.symbol != null)
            {
                return model[KB.symbol];    
            }
            else if ( KB.connetives == "AND")
            {
                foreach (Sentence s in KB.child)
                {
                    if(PL_True(s, model) == false) 
                    { 
                        return false; 
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            }
            else if (KB.connetives == "OR")
            {
                foreach (Sentence s in KB.child)
                {
                    if (PL_True(s, model) == true)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            }
            else if (KB.connetives == "AND")
            {
                foreach (Sentence s in KB.child)
                {
                    if (PL_True(s, model) == false)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            }
            else if (KB.connetives == "IF")
            {
                Sentence left = KB.child[0];
                Sentence right = KB.child[KB.child.Count - 1];

                if (PL_True(left,model) == true || PL_True(right,model) == false)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
            else if (KB.connetives == "IFF")
            {
                Sentence left = KB.child[0];
                Sentence right = KB.child[KB.child.Count - 1];

                if (PL_True(left, model) == true && PL_True(right, model) == false)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
            else if (KB.connetives == "NOT")
            {
                Sentence opposite = KB.child[0];
               
                if (PL_True(opposite, model) == true)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }

            return false;   
        }
    
        public bool TT_Entails(Sentence KB, Sentence Alpha)
        {
            List<string> symbol1 = ExtractSymbol(KB);
            List<string> symbol2 = ExtractSymbol(Alpha);
            List<string> symbols = new List<string>();

            symbols.Concat(symbol1);
            symbols.Concat(symbol2);
            Dictionary<string, bool> table = new();
            return TT_Check_All(KB, Alpha, symbols, table );
        }
    
        private bool TT_Check_All(Sentence KB, Sentence Alpha, List<string> symbol, Dictionary<string, bool> model)
        {
            if(symbol.Count == 0)
            {
                if(PL_True(KB, model) == true)
                {
                    return PL_True(Alpha, model);   
                }

                return false;
            }

            string p = symbol[0];
            symbol.RemoveAt(0);
            List<string> rest = symbol;

            return TT_Check_All(KB, Alpha, rest, model.Add(p,true)) && TT_Check_All(KB, Alpha, rest, model.Add(p, false));
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Presumably `model.Add` is a void method, which would make sense.  Why do you think it would return a value?  And what is the type of the parameter that you are passing to `TT_Check_All`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Add` method on the dictionary returns `void`. So when you pass the result of `model.Add(p, false)` into `TT_Check_All` recursively, you are passing a `void` rather than the expected `Dictionary<string, bool>` type.

You can solve this issue by doing the `Add` before the recursive call and passing in model.